# Laravel 5.5 Session getting lost on each request

Tags: php, session, redis, laravel-5.5

When logging in, authentication works and the user is redirected to the logged-in page (/home at first but I also tried changing to /dashboard) but then the session seems to become lost as it shows an empty array when logging on the logged-in controller.

My setup involves using Redis as a session store but I have tried file and database drives as well with the same results.

Even stranger, I am able to view the session data in my redis cli without any issues.

Some "fixes" I have tried to no avail are:
 - removing underscores from session cookie name (as well as dashes/hyphens)
 - changing session domain setting to all combinations of main domain and subdomain

Does anyone have any ideas on any other possible fixes?

UPDATE:

Other fixes tried:

- alternative session drivers (file, database, and cookie)
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan clear-compiled`

Answer (score 1):

Where did you write your Routes ?
Please note that the `web` middleware uses the default Laravel Session.

So routes written in `routes/web.php` are the ones using Laravel Session. You can also try using the file driver, but make sure the `/storage` folder has at 0755 permission.

also, can you please check you `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`s `mapWebRoutes()` method looks like this?

```
/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

Assuming you didn't modify the `app\Http\Kernel.php`

Comment: They are in routes/web.php and I can give it a shot

Comment: I see files being added to storage/framework/sessions but the issue is still happening

Comment: Edited and added some additional checks on original answer

Comment: My RouteServiceProvider matches what you have and the only edit I made to Kernel.php is I uncommented \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class in the web middleware group but I have tried commenting it out again to no avail

Comment: Please run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan clear-compiled` after un-commenting that line and then try again.

Comment: cache:clear and clear-compiled had no effect as far as I can tell

Comment: Is this happening in your production environment too? What's your environment setup (stack) where you're facing this issue? e.g., Ubuntu 14.04, nginx, php-fpm, MySQL etc

Comment: yes, it's happening in production. I'm using a basic LAMP stack based on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @user3534846 did you find a solution?

Comment: the problem resolved with me after remove             `\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class` from `web` in `app\Http\Kernel.php`

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved with me after remove `\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class` from `web` inside `$middlewareGroups` in `app\Http\Kernel.php` file.